# php multiple array with same key

Tags: php

I know there is huge posts about this problem.. but I'm failed to fixed this with my little knowledge. Hope someone who expertise this filed maybe help!

Here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => 9
            [course] => 80
            [subject] => 759
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => 9
            [course] => 80
            [subject] => 760
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => 11
            [course] => 97
            [subject] => 862
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category] => 11
            [course] => 97
            [subject] => 865
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category] => 11
            [course] => 97
            [subject] => 866
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [category] => 11
            [course] => 87
            [subject] => 758
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [category] => 9
            [course] => 25
            [subject] => 125
        )

)
```

Now I want to print same key value once only. So my expected result like this:

## category 9

- course 80 = subject 759, 760
- course 25 = subject 125

## category 11

- course 97 = subject 862, 865, 866
- course 87 = subject 758

I tried from yesterday night but can't print same key value once like this

Comment: you expected results is an array or a string like `subject 862, 865, 866` ?

Comment: expected as string sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to rearrange the array:

```
<?php
    $newarray = [];
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        $newarray[$entry['category']][$entry['course']] .= ' ' . $entry['subject'];
    }
?>
```

It may need some validation and changes, but you should end up with an array of organized data.

Comment: Thank you so much sir :) <3 Lots of love for you